# Написать программу на С. Матрица размером 10х10 из целых чисел

Tags: c, массивы, матрицы

Написать программу на С.
Имеем матрицу размером 10х10 из целых чисел. Элементы массива вводятся пользователем. Найти произведение положительных элементов на главной диагонали матрицы.

Код, который смогла написать, но не полностью.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
    int A [9][9];
    int i, j;
    int range;
    printf ("enter a range of numbers\n");  // Ввод диапазона случайных чисел
    scanf ("%d", &range);  // Ввод массива
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < 10; j++)
            A[i][j] = rand() % range + 1;  

    printf("array\n");  // Вывод массива
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < 10; j++)
            printf("%d\n", A[i][j]);
    printf("\n");
    getch();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: И в чём собственно проблема с умножением чисел на диагонали?  И почему в матрице размерностью **9х9** используются индексы 9?

Comment: Проблема в том, что при выполнении программы и вводе случайных чисел нужная матрица не получается , а выводит на экран несколько столбцов с ранее введенными числами и другой размерностью  . Размерность 10х10 , но т.к.  нумерация столбцов и строк идет с 0, то использовала 9х9.

Comment: 1) Произведение чисел на диагонали будет не матрица, а число. 2) Представленный код просто генерирует и печатает матрицу, причём каждый элемент выводится в своей строке, вместо построчного вывода.  3) У вас будет выход за границы массива в циклах, так как для матрицы размером '9х9' допустимы индексы от 0 до 8 включительно.

Comment: Поняла, большое спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int mult=1;
for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
if(A[i][i]>0)mult*=A[i][i];
}
return mult;
```